# C++14: How can I use my template function with `iterator` and `const_iterator`

Tags: c++, iterator

So I have these two functions which should make it more pleasant to check whether a key exists in a map:

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T>
bool isEqualToEndOfMap(const typename Map<K, T>::iterator &it, const Map<K, T> &map) {
    return it == map.end();
}

template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T>
bool isInMap(const K &key, const Map<K, T> &map) {
    return isEqualToEndOfMap(map.find(key), map);
}
```

But unfortunately, `map.find()` returns an `std::map::const_iterator` which is incompatible with `std::map::iterator`. I can't change to `const typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator` because I want to use `isEqualToEndOfMap` with regular iterators (non const), due to this:

```
const auto ret = std::find_if(mmap.begin(), mmap.end(),
                                    [streamShm](const std::pair<int, StreamMapContainer> pair) {
                                        return pair.second.pcktRefShm->id() == streamShm->id();
                                    });
if(isEqualToEndOfMap(ret, mmap))
```

`std::find_if` returns a regular iterator because `map.begin()` and `map.end()` are returning regular iterators. Sure, casting is possible. But it is even uglier:

`std::map<int, StreamMapContainer>::const_iterator(..)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of points:

1. There is no need to for `isEqualToEndOfMap` to accept the iterator by reference.
2. You may use a `const_iterator` as the argument type in `isEqualToEndOfMap`. An object of type `iterator` can be used in a call to the function.

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T>
bool isEqualToEndOfMap(typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator it, const Map<K, T> &map) {
    return it == map.end();
}
```

That should work in both use cases in your posted code.

#### Update, in response to OP's comment.

In a comment, you wrote:

> But even if is cheap, why not avoid it?

You have to explore your options and decide which one is the best for your needs.

In addition to what I already suggested, I can think of two more options.

#### Option 2

Have couple of overloads, one for `const_iterator` and one for `iterator`.

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T>
bool isEqualToEndOfMap(const typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator &it, const Map<K, T> &map) {
    return it == map.end();
}

template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T>
bool isEqualToEndOfMap(const typename Map<K, T>::iterator &it, const Map<K, T> &map) {
    return it == map.end();
}
```

This is not better than the first option since you have to maintain essentially duplicate code.

#### Option 3

Use `const_iterator&` as the argument type instead of `const_iterator`.

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T>
bool isEqualToEndOfMap(const typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator &it, const Map<K, T> &map) {
    return it == map.end();
}
```

This saves you a copy when the function is called with a `const_iterator` but still requires a copy, a temporary object, when it is called with an `iterator` object.

You could potentially use this option but it is not idiomatic. Iterator objects are meant to be used almost as thought they are pointers and passed by value.

My recommendation would be to stick with the first option.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulSanders.

Comment: @RSahu Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I don't understand why I shouldn't pass the iterator as a reference? Wouldn't this be a "Call by copy" otherwise?

Comment: @binary Copying an iterator is cheap.

Comment: @PaulSanders But even if is cheap, why not avoid it?

Comment: Because it is, in fact, cheaper to pass it by value than by reference.  Most iterators are a pointer under the skin and that is a primitive type.

Answer (score 2):

Why not two templates:

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T>
bool isEqualToEndOfMap(const typename Map<K, T>::iterator &it, const Map<K, T> &map) {
    return it == map.end();
}
```

and:

```
template<template <typename...> class Map, typename K, typename T>
bool isEqualToEndOfMap(const typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator &it, const Map<K, T> &map) {
    return it == map.end();
}
```